# Is it possible to start the visual debugger in vscode from a terminal?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I can start interactive debugging with the buttons provided in the `run and debug` pane, configured with a `launch.json`. I am using the gnu c++ compiler `g++` from msys2.
When using it, I do get a commandline in the terminal that is first compiling the code, then a seperate debug terminal is opened with another commandline which then enables the visual debug session.

But copying and executing these commands doesen't give me an interactrive debug session.
Is it even possible?
What does it need to start an interactive debug session in the visual debugger of vscode from the commandline?

Comment: how would you start the debug interface from the terminal, VSC needs to connect to the debugger, just setup a launch config and press F5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if you can type command in terminal that launches debugging in VS Code - I think answer is you can't.

If you want to use debugger in terminal, you should stick with using `gdb`.

Comment: Yes, it's about type a command in terminal that launches debugging in VSCode.
It would be really nice to have that...

I know that gdb as a commandline tool should work in a terminal, but that is not what i asked for.

You "think" the answer is no - so you are not sure about that?

Is there still a chance for it?
Maybe some workaround that can be invoked by the terminal ?